# What is the purpose of the "if" statement in a mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php

Based off what I found online you should use this for error handling but I am still confused on the purpose of this. If before establishing a connection I have a check in place to make sure the connection has been established and if I have a query that does not take any user input such as "select * from table" why would I need to use the the "if" statement when preparing my query?

This is the code block I'm referencing

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, that would allow you to handle cases where the prepare fails.

See [the prepare manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-returnvalues):

> mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.

If the prepare fails, `$stmt` will be `false` rather than an object, and any other methods you try to call on it will result in fatal errors, so the idea with that `if` check is to detect the error earlier so you can handle the failure more gracefully.

```
... else {
    $mysqli->error;  // log this and/or react to it somehow
}
```

Comment: I totally understand the purpose of this but can you give me an example of where one of these "errors" would occur?

Comment: prepare() can fail for various reasons not dependent on user input. A syntax error is a common example that people ask about here fairly often. Or maybe the query worked properly at one point and then *someone* altered the table.